# Python Multiprocessing cannot Join for Large Data Set

Tags: python, pandas, join, multiprocessing, large-data

I am trying compute cosine similarity of 260774x96 data matrix. I was using full size Dataframe to compute the cosine similarity, and using this code.
`similarities = cdist(Dataframe, Dataframe, metric='cosine')`.

However, the Jupyter Notebook run out memory(64GB) and crash the kernel. So that I decide to compute single row with Dataframe each time, and then sort, trim and save it each loop. The issue is it takes too much times, about 12 hours.

So I applied multiprocessing to speed up, for small size data it works, single row compute with 500 rows Dataframe. However, computing single row with full size Dataframe, the process can work and put data to the queue, but the join() just not work. The main function keep running even the child process was end with no error. I try to print the queue in another cell, it has full data.

Anther problem is input data queue cannot take full size Dataframe, it show Full error.

I don't know what is the problem the program just stuck on join() step. Or is other practical way to have parallel computing.

```
from multiprocess import Lock, Process, Queue, current_process,Array,Lock
from time import time
import queue  # imported for using queue.Empty exception
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from scipy.spatial import distance
# from cos_process import cos_process
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances



def cos_process(idx, result_queue, index_queue,df_data_only_numpy):
    print(f"process start {current_process().name}")
    # for shrik the data size, so that the multiprocessing Join can work.
    # df_data_only_numpy = df_data_only_numpy[:500]
    while True:

        try:
            task_index_list = index_queue.get_nowait()


        except queue.Empty:

            break
        else:
            cosine_dict = {}
            for i in task_index_list:


                similarities = cdist([df_data_only_numpy[i]], df_data_only_numpy, metric='cosine')
                sorted_save_data = np.sort(similarities[0])[:20] # output the cosine simlarities data after sorted
                sorted_save_key = (np.argsort(similarities[0])[:20]) #output the index of sorted simlarities
                # make a dictionary {index:{index:cosine,index:cosine},....}
                cosine_dict[i]={int(i):float(data) if data==data else (data) for i,data in zip(sorted_save_key,sorted_save_data) }
#             print(cosine_dict)
            try:
                # put the dictionary data to queue
                result_queue.put_nowait(cosine_dict)
            except queue.Full:
                print("queue full in process")


    print(f"end process {current_process().name}")
    

    return True


def main():

    number_of_processes = 10 # create 10 processes for computer
    process_compute_time = 1000  # each process run 1000 rows in the while loop
    df_data_only_numpy = df_data_only.to_numpy()
    index_queue = Queue()  # index of the df
    result_queue = Queue()  # store the output of the similarity
    processes = []


    # for idx in df_data_only.T:
    # only test 1000 rows data in this case, the dataframe has 260774 rows and 96 columns
    for idx in range(0, 1000, process_compute_time):
        try:
            index_queue.put_nowait(list(range(idx, idx+process_compute_time)))  
        except queue.Full:
            print("full")
            
    print("creating process")
    # creating processes
    for w in range(number_of_processes):
        p = Process(target=cos_process, args=(index_queue, result_queue, index_queue,df_data_only_numpy))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

        
    # completing process 
    for p in processes:
        print("before join")
        p.join()
        print("finish join")

        # print the output

    while not result_queue.empty():
        print(result_queue.get())

    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I also faced the same problem long time ago and didn't find any direct solution for my use case. The problem is Pandas is not ideal for multiprocessing. As a workaround I had to create a custom self made queue for the results of each process and join the data myself. Now you can find more information like in this [medium post](https://scollay.medium.com/multiprocessing-pandas-46-95-faster-dataframe-enhancements-c65ef29f03b1). Nevertheless if you want natively multiprocessing for bigdata take a look at [pySpark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/index.html)

Comment: For various reasons, both `pandas` as well as jupyter are not well suited for multiprocessing (not to say it can't be done); you would likely be better suited using a traditional editor (where it can run an entire file with the non-interactive interpreter), and if possible, taking individual columns as numpy arrays (which can be shared between processes using `mp.shared_memory`). Another option might be if you can put your df to disk, and read it as a mmap from multiple processes. This runs the risk of making your storage speed the bottleneck however..

Comment: I used Jupyter Notebook, I did find the Notebook has issue with multiprocessing library, so I replace multiprocessing to multiprocess library.

Comment: I did try the code on terminal, it has the same result, the processes cannot be joined.  My temporary solution is creating 10 different python file, each has different range data, and save output to json file. I opened 10 terminal and run 10 python programs at same time for speeding up, then manually join all json files together.